# Сократить запись функции для оптимизации

Tags: php, функции, оптимизация

есть функция, в которой на вход подается два значения.
как сократить в ней количество операторов сравнения и условий, для оптимизации, или это уже итак минимум?

```
function test($x){
    if ($x!==0 && $x!==1) {
        return;
    }
    elseif($x == 0) {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
        echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function test($x){
  if ($x == 1) {
    echo 0;
  } elseif ($x == 0) {
    echo 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: @inDee нет, не нужна

Answer (score 0):

> *как сократить количество операторов сравнения и условий, для оптимизации, или это уже итак минимум?*

Можно существенно сократить код, используя вместо условий массив в комбинации с коалесцентным оператором:

```
function test($x, $a = [1, 0]) {
    echo $a[$x] ?? null;
}
```

Вызов `test(0)` выведет 1, `test(1)` - 0. Все остальные варианты - null.

Answer (score 0):

нашел три варианта решения

```
1 - echo !$x;
2 - echo 1-$x;
3 - echo ($x ? 0 : 1);
```

если вдруг кому будет необходимо :)